# datetime object in tuple not printing properly with template

Tags: python

I'm using string templates for pretty printing `cur.fetchall()` data from a MySQL database.

A typical tuple looks like this:

```
(('DL2C1683', 'in', datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 28, 15, 53, 27), 'hyundai i10', '11'), ('UP1S1783', 'in', datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 28, 15, 53, 57), 'honda kinetic', '11'))
```

I'm using the following code to print this tuple:

```
template = "{0:15}|{1:15}|{2:15}|{3:15}|{4:15}" 
print template.format("Registration No.", "State", "Time", "Make", "Sector") # header
for row in rows: 
    print template.format(*row)
```

The datetime object is not printing and I'm instead getting **15**, also after the header, the rows below don't align properly.

The output:

```
Registration No.|State          |Time           |Make           |Sector         
DL2C1683       |in             |15|hyundai i10    |11             
UP1S1783       |in             |15|honda kinetic  |11
```

Comment: Well, one of the the alignment problems is because `"Registration No."` has 16 characters, and you've only allocated 15.

Comment: @Aya it's not only that, look at the two `15`s

Comment: @Aya That explains the alignment problem I guess :) thanks, but the datetime is still not printing.

Comment: @jamylak Yeah, noticed that after I posted the comment. I'm not sure how `format()` copes with `datetime`. I'd probably just do `print template.format(*[str(item) for item in row])`, but there might be some magic in `format()` I'm not aware of which will do a better job.

Comment: @Aya What you just said is working `print template.format(*[str(item) for item in row])`

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: @KartikAnand Sure, but jamylak's solution is better practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some larger width eg. `25` but also add `!s` as a `.format` conversion flag to force `datetime` into a `str`

```
import datetime
template = "{0:25}|{1:25}|{2!s:25}|{3:25}|{4:25}"
rows = (('DL2C1683', 'in', datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 28, 15, 53, 27), 'hyundai i10', '11'),
        ('UP1S1783', 'in', datetime.datetime(2013, 4, 28, 15, 53, 57), 'honda kinetic', '11'))
print template.format("Registration No.", "State", "Time", "Make", "Sector") # header
for row in rows: 
    print template.format(*row)
```

---

```
Registration No.         |State                    |Time                     |Make                     |Sector                   
DL2C1683                 |in                       |2013-04-28 15:53:27      |hyundai i10              |11                       
UP1S1783                 |in                       |2013-04-28 15:53:57      |honda kinetic            |11
```

Comment: Yes it's working now, I actually didn't know how to put conversion flag!